# how to change FQDN in ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns

I tried to change the FQDN in Ubuntu using `sudo -i gedit /etc/hosts` and change as shown below:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   ubuntu.example.com
192.168.217.129 ubuntu.example.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

after that I tried:

```
hostname -f
```

which shows:

```
hostname: Name or service not known
```

How can I change the FQDN?

Comment: Try the most popular answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04

Comment: The below link will help you. http://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-04

Comment: Well what'ya know!

Comment: rather than using sudo with gedit, might I suggest nano?  It's quite easy.  Occasionaly, `vi` is the only real option -- but I think that's realistically only for visudo.  I wouldn't mix gedit and sudo, myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hostname` and put `ubuntu`

```
echo "ubuntu" > /etc/hostname
```

Put `hostname` entry as well in following format in `/etc/hosts`

```
IP  fqdn   hostname
```

Your `/etc/hosts` should look like

```
  127.0.0.1   localhost
  127.0.1.1   ubuntu.example.com  ubuntu
  192.168.217.129 ubuntu.example.com  ubuntu 
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
```